# Joomla module to communicate with users in frontend

Tags: php, joomla, frontend

I need to receive some information from my Joomla site users (logged in users) via front-end.

I like to receive those information as form fields. After these information are saved by user he should be able to view those information and manipulate them if he likes to. I also like that some fields can determine if other fields get visible or invisible.

For example if user has chosen an European country as his country, specific fields should become visible to him. Or if he has chosen an Asian country different fields should be shown. What module or component do you suggest me that enables me to create and edit user forms via front-end and in fact receive their feedback and simultaneously enables me to change some field values based on other fields?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Chronoforms? It's very popular. http://www.chronoengine.com/downloads/chronoforms.html
You can also use a http://www.component-creator.com to store all that feedback and information in a custom made component.